# TypeError: items is undefined while reading a json using fetch in reactjs

Tags: json, reactjs, api

This is the first time I'm working with APIs using ReactJS. I know the basics of reactjs pretty well but I'm unable to read the response. I've a json response from youtube api[image].

Initially i got

> TypeError: items.map is not a function.

But then i realized that i might be getting an Object and not an array. I solved the problem by `items: json.statistics`. But now I'm getting other error i.e

> TypeError: items is undefined

I just want to fetch 3 information viz `viewCount`, `subscriberCount` and `videoCount`. I've written this code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           items: [],
           isLoaded: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UCOYqNBjmWF8j-PzI7ZPjt_w&key=AIzaSyAMeZQW6sUQgLdDTnMVeokfbcFcT2A9SuA')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                items: json.statistics
            })
        });
    }

    render() {
        var {isLoaded, items} = this.state;
        if(!isLoaded) {
              return (<div>Loading...</div>)
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div>
                   <ul>
                      {
                         items.map(item => (
                           <li key={item.id}>
                              Total views: {item.viewCount} 
                              Total subscribers: {item.subscriberCount}
                              Total videos: {item.videoCount}
                           </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            )
          }
      }
   }

    export default App;
```

Comment: Please clarify what the 'other error' is that you're getting so the community can help

Comment: ok. edited that part. plz help.

Comment: Have you tried `json.items.statistics`?

Comment: items is an array and access it with index

Comment: @caladeve. yes. `myitems: json.items.statistics`. But still i'm getting that error. I even changed the name of my variable so that it doesn't coincide with any other varibale of json response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the problem is in your `setState()`. Try something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      isLoaded: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UCOYqNBjmWF8j-PzI7ZPjt_w&key=AIzaSyAMeZQW6sUQgLdDTnMVeokfbcFcT2A9SuA"
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(({ items }) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    var { isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (!isLoaded) return <div>Loading...</div>;
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {items.map(({ id, statistics }) => (
            <li key={id}>
              Total views: {statistics.viewCount}
              Total subscribers: {statistics.subscriberCount}
              Total videos: {statistics.videoCount}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Also, you don't need an `if else` statement if you have a `return`. Either use a ternary operator or just remove the `else`.

[Here's the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-keldysh-9mcw3) if you want to take a look at it. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Its working perfectly. thanks. So I've to use `{statistics}` inside `map`. What difference will it make btw?

Comment: `statistics` object don't have `id`, this code will give warning for unique key.

Comment: You're right. I've updated the answer so that it takes the `id` from items.

Comment: @Tanzeel Using `{ statistics }` in this case is the same as using `items.statistics`, because you're mapping over the items array. It's called `destructuring` in ES6. Check out [this article](https://codeburst.io/es6-destructuring-the-complete-guide-7f842d08b98f) which explains it very well.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting data in `items` array, you need to set `json.items` in state,

```
this.setState({
    isLoaded: true,
    items: json.items
})
```

And then you will get `statistics` object data,

```
{
    items.map(item => (
        <li key={item.id}>
          Total views: {item.statistics.viewCount} 
          Total subscribers: {item.statistics.subscriberCount}
          Total videos: {item.statistics.videoCount}
        </li>
    ))
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yqqkjb)

Comment: oh. I'm so sorry I was either using `Total views: {item.viewCount} ` or `Total views: {statistics.viewCount} `. I didn't realize that it has to be `Total views: {item.statistics.viewCount} `